# How to get deletion date of custom object in salesforce

Tags: file, symfony, date, salesforce

I have a custom object in `Salesforce` called `File_Uploaded__c`:
When I upload a file in my `web application (Symfony2)`,
I save its information(size, name,...) in `Salesforce`,
but the file in question is registered in a `server`.

And when I delete the file from `salesforce`, I need to delete it from the `server` after 10 days to gain space in the `server` but I don't know how to get the `deletion date`.

I tried  to add a filed of type `Formula` in `File_Uploaded__c` where I compare the current date with the  `last modified date` and if it's more than 10 days I return `true` but it doesn't seem to work because `last modified date` could be `update date` and not only `deletion date`.

Answer (score 0):

Mark object in SF as deleted. It will be there for 10 days. After you delete file from server, delete object from SF.

Direct answer on your question:
`[Select Id from File_Uploaded__c isDeleted = true ALL ROWS]`